# UITextField attributedText property cannot be set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I create a `NSMutableAttributedString` and I try to assign it to the `textField.attributedText` property, but it doesn't work.

**Situation Description:**

1) Initially I have a `prefix` and a `placeholder` for the `textField`

[image]

2) When I enter the `phone number`, the `placeholder` gets replaced and a kearning of `x points` is added at location 2.

[image]

3) After I delete all the digits and end editing, **all the text is formatted with a kearning of 2 points**!? and I have no idea why.

[image]

**My solution:**
I created an empty `NSMutableAttributedString` (finalString) and I appended the 2 `NSMutableAttributedString's` `(prefix + placeholder or digit)`, each formatted accordingly.

**The code is:**

```
(void)updateAttributedTextFieldPrefix:(NSString *)prefix andText:(NSString *)newText {

NSMutableAttributedString * finalString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""];

// Create the Prefix String
NSMutableAttributedString * subString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:prefix];
[subString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:kGray range:NSMakeRange(0, [prefix length])];
[finalString appendAttributedString:subString];

// Create the Phone Number String
NSMutableAttributedString * phoneNumber = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:newText];
[phoneNumber addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:kWhite range:NSMakeRange(0, [phoneNumber length])];
[finalString appendAttributedString:phoneNumber];

// Add kearning between the two components
[finalString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] range:NSMakeRange([prefix length] - 1, 1)];
// Addidng the bold font
UIFont *font16 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16];
[finalString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font16 range:NSMakeRange(0, [finalString length])];

// LINE THAT HAS NO EFFECT !!!
self.textFieldForPhone.attributedText = finalString;

}
```

Why isn't the attributedText property set? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have a same issue now, do you find any solution for your issue?

Comment: Nope, I've just left it without that space between the prefix and the phone number.